# How to delete a Member in a "JsonArray" if I only know its "UniqiueId"?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

I've a JSON file like this:

```
{
"Groups": [
    {
        "UniqueId": "Footballer",
        "Region": "Europe",
        "Members": [
            {
                "UniqueId": "MANU",
                "Name": "Rooney",
                "JerseyNumber": "10",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "CITY",
                "Name": "Aguero",
                "JerseyNumber": "10",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "RM",
                "Name": "Ronaldo",
                "JerseyNumber": "7",
                "Position": "Forward"
            }]
    }]
}
```

I'm displaying a member details, say details of Rooney in a page using `ObservableCollection` and `DataModel`. I've the `UniqueId` of that member (say `UniqueId = MANU` for Rooney) in my current page.

What I want to do is when I press the Delete Button I want to delete the Member and its details from the JSON file.

Is there any way to find the `Index` of a member by searching the JSON file with its `UniqueId` and delete that Member at that position? Like `membersArray.RemoveAt(index)`. If this is possible How can I get the index number?

Or is there a better method?

**Update:**

This is my `DataModel` class:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem(String uniqueId, String name, String jerseynumber, String position)
    {
        this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.Name = name;
        this.JerseyNumber = jerseynumber;
        this.Position = position;
    }

    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string JerseyNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Position { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }   
}

public class DataGroup
{
    public DataGroup(String uniqueId, String region)
    {
        this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.Region = region;
        this.Members = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
    }

    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public string Region { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Members { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

public sealed class ReadFromJson
{
    private static ReadFromJson _readFromJson = new ReadFromJson();

    private ObservableCollection<DataGroup> _groups = new ObservableCollection<DataGroup>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataGroup> Groups
    {
        get { return this._groups; }
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<DataGroup>> GetGroupsAsync()
    {
        await _readFromJson.GetSampleDataAsync();
        return _readFromJson.Groups;
    }

    public static async Task<DataGroup> GetGroupAsync(string uniqueId)
    {
        await _readFromJson.GetSampleDataAsync();
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
        var matches = _readFromJson.Groups.Where((group) => group.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    public static async Task<DataItem> GetItemAsync(string uniqueId)
    {
        await _readFromJson.GetSampleDataAsync();
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
        var matches = _readFromJson.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Members).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
    {
        if (this._groups.Count != 0)
            return;

        StorageFile file2 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Data2.json");
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file2);

        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();
        foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
        {
            JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
            DataGroup group = new DataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                            groupObject["Region"].GetString());

            foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Members"].GetArray())
            {
                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                group.Members.Add(new DataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                               itemObject["Name"].GetString(),
                                               itemObject["JerseyNumber"].GetString(),
                                               itemObject["Position"].GetString()));
            }
            this.Groups.Add(group);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you are taking the problem from the right angle. In my mental picture, the observable collection is the central piece and it both reflects toward the UI and the JSON file via a change event. If you delete an element, the change event is fired and the collection serialized back to the JSON file.

Comment: My question is how to delete an element by only knowing its `UniqueId`.

Comment: You are trying to remove the element directly in the JSON File. My answer is that I recommend you to remove it from the collection instead and re-write the JSON file afterwards.

Comment: How can I delete using collection?

Comment: Something like: var stuffToRemove = prods.SingleOrDefault( s => s.ID == 1 ); collection.Remove( stuffToRemove );

Comment: I've **updated** my question with the `Datamodel` class included. Can you please suggest me how can I delete using `UniqueId` for this data model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89857/discussion-between-rishin-ali-and-tim-bourguignon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
JsonArray membersArray = ...

IJsonValue memberValue = null;

foreach (IJsonValue jsonValue in membersArray)
{
    if (jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedString("UniqueId") == "MANU")
    {
        memberValue = jsonValue;
        break;
    }
}

if (memberValue != null)
{
    bool removed = membersArray.Remove(memberValue);
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Created a file and stringified into the file. No errors. But when I open and read the Json no change. Nothing deleted.

Comment: When you debug the code, is `JsonArray.Remove(...)` called? Are you saving and reading from the same file? When debugging, you can always do `Debug.WriteLine(membersArray.Stringify());` and see the JSON string in the Output window.

Comment: I'm saving and reading the same file. When I call `Debug.WriteLine(membersArray.Stringify());` immediately after the `membersArray.Remove(memberObject);` the Output window is not showing.

Comment: Ok, a reference to the `IJsonValue` is needed. Answer updated.

Comment: Yes, the deletion is working fine now. But why it is not updating in my `ListView` when I go back to the mainpage?

Comment: Because your array is a static source, not an observable source. That was my very first comment: removing the information from the JSON part does not reflect on your lists and thus does not reflect on your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Single out the element in the collection, then remove it. I don't have a compiler to check it out right now, but it should be close enough.

```
DataItem item = this.Members.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == 42);
if (item != null)
    this.Members.Remove(item);
```

Comment: This is not working. Showing no definition for Members. If I'm trying to delete a member from another page how can I do that?

Comment: Which collection do you want to remove an item from? And from where in your code? "this.Members" I picked up from your code...

Comment: I'm Listing every members in `Members` array in my main page using `ListView` on `LoadState`. ListView only uses the Name of that member. I'm displaying the details (say `Name`, `JerseyNumber`, `Position`) of a clicked member from ListView, in another page (display page). In display page I've a delete button. From the display page I want delete the member and its details when is click the delete button.